# How to form a confidence band around the trend fitted from time series data

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval, arima

I have a time series data set.  I can decompose it and get the trend but I would like to put confidence ranges around the trend (past) not the forecast-ed component.  The decompose function also doesn't handle N/As very well so is there another way to define the trend with data that has N/As.  I have been trying to use Holt-Winters and ARIMA but neither seem to be able to do this.